# How to get a list of cities surrounding a city of interest (surrounding suburbs) on google maps api

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We need to find and list all the cities that are touching the border of a city of interest - For example, search Ryde, NSW - we are trying to find a list of every city that is touching the border of Ryde, NSW.

We tried radius search, but for example - if we choose a 3km standard radius search, then we search a city that is 10km wide by 10 km in length - then the 3km radius would not even reach the city boundaries.

Any ideas on what to query to avoid this, or a method to get this list?

Answer (score 0):

Google's documentation do not treat about your problem. However, I find a way using google maps api and GeoNames api. Unfortunately, you may have a account in GeoNames api and Google maps api.

You can consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649459/how-to-find-the-nearest-cities-in-google-map-api) in Stack Overflow, download the [complete dump](http://www.geonames.org/export/) of GeoNames or consult the [documentation](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html).

This code do the job:

```
/*
* Get cities based on city name and radius in KM
*/

// get geocode object as array from The Google Maps Geocoding API
$geocodeObject = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={CITY NAME},{COUNTRY CODE}'), true);

// get latitude and longitude from geocode object
$latitude = $geocodeObject['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$longitude = $geocodeObject['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

// set request options
$responseStyle = 'short'; // the length of the response
$citySize = 'cities15000'; // the minimal number of citizens a city must have
$radius = 30; // the radius in KM
$maxRows = 30; // the maximum number of rows to retrieve
$username = '{YOUR USERNAME}'; // the username of your GeoNames account

// get nearby cities based on range as array from The GeoNames API
$nearbyCities = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat='.$latitude.'&lng='.$longitude.'&style='.$responseStyle.'&cities='.$citySize.'&radius='.$radius.'&maxRows='.$maxRows.'&username='.$username, true));

// foreach nearby city get city details
foreach($nearbyCities->geonames as $cityDetails)
{
    // do something per nearby city
}
```

**Note,** *this answer do not resolve the problem with google maps api and node.js only. This post can be edited or you can take a part of it in order to add your own answer.*

*This post use also a code witch is given in an other answer in Stack Overflow in this [address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649459/how-to-find-the-nearest-cities-in-google-map-api).*

*Sphynx Tech*